# zend framework redirector->gotoUrl() with target=_blank

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

On submitting a form I want to sent my visitor to an external url to do something but hope he will continue browsing my site afterwards. In html I would give him that opportunity with href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank".

But I cannot find how to do that when I do:

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('http://www.example.com');
```

within my controller action. Nothing found in Google, documentation nor SO. Is it just not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. You can't tell the browser what to do in this scenario.

Comment: Well, `<a href='http://www.example.com' target='_blank'>link</a>` will cause the browser to open a new window. -1

Comment: That's client-side, and yes, that's possible. But server-side, you can't trigger a webbrowser to open a new window/tab.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You can do this with an `<a>` tag, but not a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that effect with the help of Javascript:

1. submit the form
2. on success, open a new tab with the external page with JS
3. redirect to a new location within your app on the old tab

Comment: Thx, I will look into that. Where would my visitor end up: on the external page or in the new app location? I remember sometimes frantically clicking a page which I thought did not perform the required action only finding afterwards tens of inactive browser tabs with the required page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now:

$link = new PTA_Link();
$link->setTarget('_blank');